# Loop without ending a stream

Tags: python, loops

I have some Python code and with that code I can retrieve appointments from my Google Calendar.
The code will loop every 15 minutes and will look for an appointment with a special word in the title.
If it finds an event, a audiostream will be started and it will end approx. 15 minutes after the event is over.
This works fine.

But, because of the 15 minute loop (time.sleep(900), the audiostream will be cut and started again.
I cannot figure out how to change the code so it don't cut off the stream, but keeps playing.
I think I have to use an If construction (simple version: If event is found And omxplayer = playing, Then  skip loop.

Below is my code.
Can anybody help me ?

```
# Google Calendar API instellen en credentials.json opslaan
# https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/go
# https://mediamagazine.nl/live-links-nederland/livestreams-nederland-landelijk/

from __future__ import print_function
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import datetime
import pickle
import os.path
import time
import os
import psutil
from subprocess import Popen
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly']

def checkIfProcessRunning(processName):
    '''
    Check if there is any running process that contains the given name processName.
    '''
    #Iterate over the all the running process
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            # Check if process name contains the given name string.
            if processName.lower() in proc.name().lower():
                return True
        except (psutil.NoSuchProcess, psutil.AccessDenied, psutil.ZombieProcess):
            pass
    return False;

def button_snooze(channel):
    os.system('killall omxplayer.bin')
    print("Snoozing")
    
def button_play(channel):
    os.system('killall omxplayer.bin')
    omxc = Popen(['omxplayer', '-b', 'http://playerservices.streamtheworld.com/api/livestream-redirect/RADIO538.mp3'])
    print("Playing audiostream")
    time.sleep(14400) # Play stream for 14400 seconds (4 hours).
    
def button_shutdown(channel):
    os.system('killall omxplayer.bin')
    time.sleep(3)
    omxc = Popen(['omxplayer', '-b', '/home/pi/Music/shutting_down.mp3'])
    print("Shutting down")
    time.sleep(7)
    #os.system("pkill -9 -f read_googlecalendar.py")
    os.system("sudo shutdown -h now")
    

def main():
    
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)  # Ignore warning for now
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) # Use physical pin numbering
    
    # Declare button to shutdown Raspberry Pi
    # Don't forget to add a "1 kOhm" resistor between each pushbutton and GPIO pin or you'll fry your pins !!!
    GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
    GPIO.add_event_detect(13,GPIO.RISING,callback=button_shutdown, bouncetime=2000)

    """Shows basic usage of the Google Calendar API.
    Prints the start and name of the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Calendar API
    timenow = str(datetime.datetime.now())
    now = str(datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat()) + 'Z'
    now_plus_1_minute = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes = -119)
    now_plus_1_minute_iso = now_plus_1_minute.isoformat() + 'Z'
    
    print('Getting the upcoming events in 1 minute')
    # Kalender primary aanpassen in andere kalender.
    events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=now, timeMax=now_plus_1_minute_iso,
                                        maxResults=10, singleEvents=True,
                                        orderBy='startTime').execute()
    events = events_result.get('items', [])

    if not events:
        print('No upcoming events found.')
        print("Het is nu: " + timenow)
        # Stop playing internetradio
        os.system('killall omxplayer.bin')
        print ("")
                
    for event in events:
            if event.has_key('summary'):
                if 'Wakker' in event['summary']:
                    start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
                    print("Het is nu: " + timenow)
                    print ("")
                    print(start, event['summary'])
                    # Stop playing internetradio
                    #os.system('killall omxplayer.bin')
                    # Start playing internetradio
                    omxc = Popen(['omxplayer', 'http://playerservices.streamtheworld.com/api/livestream-redirect/RADIO538.mp3'])
                    print ("")
                    print ("=========================")
                    print ("")
                    #time.sleep(14400) # Play stream for 14400 seconds (4 hours).
    
    
while True:
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
        #time.sleep(300)  # Wait 300 seconds (5 mins) and loop script.
        #time.sleep(600)  # Wait 600 seconds (10 mins) and loop script.
        time.sleep(900)  # Wait 900 seconds (15 mins) and loop script.
        #time.sleep(10)  # Wait 10 seconds and loop script.
        print("==== REFRESH ====")
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Use a global boolean variable to keep track of whether the player is currently playing. Only start/stop it if the desired state is different from the current state.

Comment: Thomas, can you give me a hint where and how I can do this.

I think I need an extra IF in the {for event in evens} loop.
But I don't know exactly how.

Comment: Great, I found it.

I needed to add   player = True  in my code.
Then, I added a global player in my def main().

Last I set player = false in the if not events and an extra if in the for event in events.

Answer (score 0):

This is my complete code and now it works.

```
# Google Calendar API instellen en credentials.json opslaan
# https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/go
# https://mediamagazine.nl/live-links-nederland/livestreams-nederland-landelijk/

from __future__ import print_function
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import datetime
import pickle
import os.path
import time
import os
import psutil
from subprocess import Popen
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly']

player = False

def checkIfProcessRunning(processName):
    '''
    Check if there is any running process that contains the given name processName.
    '''
    #Iterate over the all the running process
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            # Check if process name contains the given name string.
            if processName.lower() in proc.name().lower():
                return True
        except (psutil.NoSuchProcess, psutil.AccessDenied, psutil.ZombieProcess):
            pass
    return False;

def button_snooze(channel):
    os.system('killall omxplayer.bin')
    print("Snoozing")
    
def button_play(channel):
    os.system('killall omxplayer.bin')
    omxc = Popen(['omxplayer', '-b', 'http://playerservices.streamtheworld.com/api/livestream-redirect/RADIO538.mp3'])
    print("Playing audiostream")
    time.sleep(14400) # Play stream for 14400 seconds (4 hours).
    
def button_shutdown(channel):
    os.system('killall omxplayer.bin')
    time.sleep(3)
    omxc = Popen(['omxplayer', '-b', '/home/pi/Music/shutting_down.mp3'])
    print("Shutting down")
    time.sleep(7)
    #os.system("pkill -9 -f read_googlecalendar.py")
    os.system("sudo shutdown -h now")
    

def main():
    global player
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)  # Ignore warning for now
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) # Use physical pin numbering
    
    # Declare button to shutdown Raspberry Pi
    # Don't forget to add a "1 kOhm" resistor between each pushbutton and GPIO pin or you'll fry your pins !!!
    GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
    GPIO.add_event_detect(13,GPIO.RISING,callback=button_shutdown, bouncetime=2000)

    """Shows basic usage of the Google Calendar API.
    Prints the start and name of the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Calendar API
    timenow = str(datetime.datetime.now())
    now = str(datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat()) + 'Z'
    now_plus_1_minute = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes = -119)
    now_plus_1_minute_iso = now_plus_1_minute.isoformat() + 'Z'
    
    print('Getting the upcoming events in 1 minute')
    # Kalender primary aanpassen in andere kalender.
    events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=now, timeMax=now_plus_1_minute_iso,
                                        maxResults=10, singleEvents=True,
                                        orderBy='startTime').execute()
    events = events_result.get('items', [])

    if not events:
        print('No upcoming events found.')
        print("Het is nu: " + timenow)
        # Stop playing internetradio
        os.system('killall omxplayer.bin')
        player = False
        print ("")
                
    for event in events:
            if event.has_key('summary'):
                if 'Wakker' in event['summary']:
                    start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
                    print("Het is nu: " + timenow)
                    print ("")
                    print(start, event['summary'])
                    # Stop playing internetradio
                    #os.system('killall omxplayer.bin')
                    # Start playing internetradio
                    if (player != True):
                        omxc = Popen(['omxplayer', 'http://playerservices.streamtheworld.com/api/livestream-redirect/RADIO538.mp3'])
                        print ("")
                        print ("=========================")
                        print ("")
                        player = True
                        #time.sleep(14400) # Play stream for 14400 seconds (4 hours).
                    elif (player == True):
                        player = True
                        print ("speelt al")
    
    
while True:
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
        #time.sleep(300)  # Wait 300 seconds (5 mins) and loop script.
        #time.sleep(600)  # Wait 600 seconds (10 mins) and loop script.
        #time.sleep(900)  # Wait 900 seconds (15 mins) and loop script.
        time.sleep(10)  # Wait 10 seconds and loop script.
        print("==== REFRESH ====")
        GPIO.cleanup()
```